# Excel formula to compare delivery date and target date with empty cells

Tags: excel, date

Working on a project tracker right now and have hit the migraine jackpot on my last formula. Column F has target date, Column G has delivery date, Cell B1 has the reporting date. I am trying to get to a formula that tells me if delivery date is lower than target date, the project is "on target" or if not is "late". This is the bit I can manage... for some of my projects (not finished) Column G is empty, I would therefore only consider them "late" if the target date (say was due on the 30/01/2017) is in the past compared to the the reporting date (30/02/2017), the others will be left blank. This is where I got to:

```
=IF(AND(G5="",F5<$B$1),"late",IF(G5="","",IF(G5<F5,"on target","late")))
```

Thank you

Comment: And what is that formula doing that is not correct?

Comment: Isn't it better to put some data (Input & Output). So, we can understand.

Comment: The formula does the" late" and "on-target" when there is data but then the formula breaks down when the cell is empty. Comparing it to cell B1 makes no difference...

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you have in mind?

`=IF(AND(G5<F5,G5<>""),"on target",IF(G5="",IF(F5<$B$1,"late",""),"late"))`

Comment: Thank you WillamD all working but the Blank cell remain a challenge, if the reporting date is in say 01/01/2020 and the cell is Bank, I would like the cell to remain blank, this lead it to say "on target" and does not change when I change the reporting date to say 01/01/2000... brain melting warning!

Comment: From my recreation of your scenario the formula result is blank when the target date is later than the reporting date and no delivery date has been specified, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Is is possible that there might be a value in the delivery date, even though it looks blank (a zero perhaps)? 

Or maybe I am not fully understanding the issue - A screenshot of a mockup demonstrating your desired output might help us help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I used the base formula in the initial post here and made a modification that worked for me.

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(R2),"",R2),OR,IF(R2<M2,"Yes","NO"))`

in my data `R` was received date, `M` is the target date and this formula was pasted in cell `V`. I did received a `#name?` error when R was left blank